# Extending the kernel and installing on real Android devices

Tags: android

I've been working on an extended Android kernel that adds an additional layer of permission-checking based on XACML2.0 policies compiled to Java code. The kernel itself isn't affected; the changes run entirely in the Java middleware within the initial Dalvik thread. This is all based on a forked version of the Froyo 2.2 kernel+middleware distro.

The changed code runs fine in the emulator. The question is how to install modified kernels on a real device; an (already unlocked) Samsung Galaxy GT-P7510 in this case. I've researched this extensively and am beginning to think it might not even be possible.

The first bad sign is that this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere I've looked. I'm not confident the generic Froyo kernel can be installed without bricking the device as it won't have Samsung's secret sauce, device drivers, and whatever it is that can be downloaded from opensource.samsung.com. I've downloaded that, and it seems to be an entirely different kernel minus the Froyo java parts. There's no sign of how to splice the Samsung and Froyo distros together, unless the secret is to overwrite parts of the prebuilt parts of Froyo with something from the Samsung build?

Backing away from the particulars, the question here is: is modifying Android kernels possible and how should I proceed.

PS: The goal is to install the modified kernel on precisely one device for an internal demo. How to distribute it more widely is a MUCH larger problem that I don't need to solve.

Comment: From the lack of responses here and elsewhere, I'm inferring that running kernel extensions for real is impossible. Extensions based on extending and compiling source code don't work because devices use vendor-specific proprietary code that isn't in Google open sources, and extending rooted ROMs doesn't work because source isn't available for these either (based on looking hard and finding none).   The only possibly I see is starting from some working ROM and replacing partitions from some other kernel; i.e. the extended one you're building. Or is there some other possibility I'm missing?

Comment: Promoted comment to an answer, then failed to find a way to delete the old comment.

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of responses here and elsewhere, I gather that running kernel extensions for real is impossible. Extensions based on extending and compiling source code don't work because devices use vendor-specific proprietary code that isn't in Google open sources. Extending rooted ROMs doesn't work because source isn't available for these either (based on looking hard and finding none).

The only possibly I see is starting from aworking ROM and replacing partitions from some other kernel; i.e. the extended one you're building. Or is there some other possibility I'm missing?